# CCDrawLine keep crashing the app after the first time

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In one app, the cocos2d iOS using `CCDrawline` to draw a line. And it always work the first time,
however, when the game exited and reenters the second time, the app would always crash at the `CCDrawline`. Commented out the app would be OK.

```
@implementation Hook

- (void)draw { 
    [super draw];
    ccDrawColor4F(14.0/255.0,118.0/255.0,188.0/255.0,1.0f);
    ccDrawLine(ccp(self.contentSize.width - 15, self.contentSize.height), ccp(253 - self.position.x,459 - self.position.y));
} 

@end


-(void)Fishing
{              // Create the hook
    Hook *hook = [Hook spriteWithTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:@"hook2_small.png"]];
    hook.position = ccp(self.fishToCatch.position.x, self.fishToCatch.position.y - 10); 
    [self addChild:hook];
    .....
}
```

Comment: What type of crash? Can you show us the console output?

Comment: you mean when the game resumes from background? In that case it would be helpful to see any code related to that, ie appdelegate methods like didEnterBackground and so forth.

Comment: enter and exit the coco2d game,(director ends)the crash is EXEC_BAD_ACCES.    The App itself doesn't exit, only the game.